# "this qualifies for" vs. "this qualifies as"

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

What is the difference between "this qualifies **for**" and "this qualifies **as**"?

I don't understand the difference between "qualifies for" and "qualifies as"

Answer (score 2):

### "Qualifies as" is for categorizing among things

When you are comparing things, you use "as" to distinguish or categorize them.

> Tom qualifies as a pilot.

Tom has a distinction that separates him from others: he is a pilot.

> Pluto does not qualify as a planet.

Pluto is not categorized as a planet because it is somehow different from those things that we do call planets.

### "Qualifies for" is for measuring status/degree against a standard

> Tom qualifies for promotion.

Tom is better than the minimum standard for the higher position.

### Note:

**When something is of particular grade, it may also be categorized differently.** 
So you have to pay attention to what you're comparing to. Are you comparing the subject to other things like it? Or to the standards used to categorize those things?

> **Tom is qualified for a pilot's license.** (He meets the standards/requirements for the license)
>
> **Tom is qualified as a pilot.** (He belongs to a subset of people who are pilots).

Answer (score 1):

"Qualifies for" means that something is eligible to participate in some event (such as a competition) or join some notable group (such as an academic achievement society).

"Qualifies as" means that something meets the criteria for *being* something, or at least for serving as something.

> That race time qualifies for the national tournament.
>
> That email qualifies as "written notice".